# How would I relate $e^{i\omega_{\mu\nu}}J^{\mu\nu}$ with lorentz transformation matrix?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, general-relativity

How to go from the given exponential form to given transformation matrix? 
[image]

Do I need to know the generators of boost and rotation? How will I find $\omega_{\mu\nu}$ and $J^{\mu\nu}$ in that case?

Comment: could you give some more context? what's $J$, what is $\omega$?

Answer (score 0):

If $J^{\mu \nu}$ are the generators of the Lorentz transformations (so should form a basis for the Lie Algebra of the Lorentz group, in particular they should be antisymmetric) and $\omega_{\mu \nu}$ are the parameters governing the Lorentz transformations, then since the generators $J^{01}$, etc. are matrices (we have a matrix Lie algebra) the exponential map back to the Lie group will just be the matrix exponential.

Hence the procedure is to calculate the matrix $A = \omega_{\mu \nu}J^{\mu \nu}$ that governs the transformation that you're doing then find your Lorentz transformation as

$$\textrm{exp}(A) = \sum_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}A^n$$

which will also be a matrix.

Comment: There are details regarding the exponential map, etc. that are group theoretic. I'm guessing that you just want to complete a calculation.

Comment: Thanx for answer. I know what you have said. But I don't know how find its explicit form. For example i have given a boost matrix in the question. lets say I want to find the boost on a 4-momentum. Then starting from exponential form how will i reach given matrix.

Comment: There is an logarithmic map that is the inverse of exp. I have never used it, but it probably has a power series expansion. With the exponential series it is only easy to compute in some special cases, I imagine that the same goes for the logarithm.